# Como selecionar o ano no PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela com dados dos funcionarios de uma empresa.
Devo mostrar quem completou um ano de trabalho na empresa.

[image: tabela]

O tipo de dados para o campo anoAdmissao: DATE (dd/mm/AA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para extrair o ano você pode usar:

```
SELECT idFuncionario, nomeFuncionario, anoAdmissao, EXTRACT (YEAR FROM anoAdmissao) AS ano FROM Tfuncionario
```

Se você quiser selecionar quem está completando um ano hoje pode usar:

```
SELECT Tfuncionario.* WHERE Mod(Trunc(sysdate) - Tfuncionario.anoAdmissao, 365 ) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assim ajuda?

```
select * from tfuncionario where anoAdmissao <= '2000/01/01' and anoAdmissao >= '1999/01/01';
```

aonde `'1999/01/01'` o inicio de uma data e `'2000/01/01'` o fim.

Comment: Posso automatizar com sydate ?

Comment: fazer um ano apos ter sido adimitido ?

Comment: Selecionar todos os funcionários que completam hoje um ano de admissão ?

Comment: sim, sim e sim @alexjosesilva

Answer (score 0):

conseguir contar os anos, porém não consegui limitar a um ano a data a ser exibida:

```
SELECT trunc((months_between(sysdate, to_date(f.ANOADMISSAO,'dd/mm/yy')))/12) AS idade
FROM tfuncionario f
```

A query irá mostrar todos os anos.